How to respect leading zero when importing in libreoffice calc
I am importing a file that one of the columns has numbers that have a leading zero or zeroes. Whenever I import the file, it is read properly during the preview:

But after accepting and opening the file it ends up removing the zero form the column

This is a CSV file and it was saved as TEXT only, but Libreoffice ends up assigning the column a numeric value automatically and ends up removing the zero. How can I make sure that, whatever I see in the preview is respected when the file if finally opened with LibreOffice Calc.

Same problem in ONLYOFFICE

@ArchismanPanigrahi I hope the same solution works as well. :D

01 23 45 67 89 : should not have any pb as it is not a number : a quick "sanitisation" of your data could transform 0123456789 into 01 23 45 67 89 ? (btw, take the opportunity to add the proper +nnn prefix, as otherwise the number only work in the proper country, but not outside of it (it would call other people inside that other country).  ie : 0123456789 into +nnn 1 23 45 67 89 the +nnn works the same inside the right country, so it's best to always include it as it then works everywhere

If it’s a phone number and is not presented in the CSV file in such a way that it is interpreted as a phone number, I would argue that the issue here lies not with the software reading the data, but with either the software that is writing the data or the format that was chosen for storing the data. At minimum I would expect apparent numbers to be quoted if exporting as ‘text only’ CSV, though I’m not sure that that will resolve your issue here.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Is that like OnlyFans but for work?

@pipe From my experience, it has better compatibility with MSOffice generated files than LibreOffice.

Try this:
Select the column in the preview.
In the selected column, change the column type to Text, from the Column Type drop-down menu
When you select the column type to Text, all values ​​in that column will be treated as text, leaving leading zeros.

@David see my answer below.

@David  Text with leading zeroes are in my experience (30 years or so) almost never numbers and there is extremely rare to do any math on them. Most common are things like phone numbers or labels such as account numbers. The leading zero is part of the lable. I have never done math on phone numbers but you might have different examples. Regardless I would import as text and if needed convert to number in a calculated column.

@David You can use the NUMBERVALUE function to convert a number formatted as text to number and do math on it, so you don't lose any functionality.

@BeastOfCaerbannog But WHY would you do math on a phone number?  It's like saying you will do math on an address, or post code.  It's /not/ a number.  Sure, you can extract the area code, just like you can with a postal code, or house number.   Just because it (generally) all digits, doesn't make it a 'number'.

@Neil My comment was a reply to David's comment: "But killing any math function being used." Most likely no one would do math on a phone number, but if one would like to for any reason, they could. Also, keep in mind that while the OP's case is about a column with phone numbers, another user with a similar issue although not about phone numbers could come across this thread. Knowing that they don't lose any functionality if they have their column with numbers formatted as text would be useful to them.

I'm just imagining someone doing "areaCode * Pi" to 'make it even more random' :-)

A time can of course be 4 digits HHMM in which the leading zero matters (0140 is definitely morning, 140 doesn't look like a time and you wouldn't know whether it was am or pm).  Of course that's really 2 numbers, HH and MM, and should be formatted as time not text.  In other cases leading zeroes are preserved for alignment in tables; that can be done with numeric formats once it's in a spreadsheet.

So this solution and @BeastOfCaerbannog's comment really are the right way to go - treat it as text; if you really need it as a number, that's OK.  And consider Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Phone Numbers to be required reading in contexts like this

I tried this with a sample file testcsv.csv with the following contents:
Name,Zip Code,ID Number
John,10034,01402243593
Jane,10034,00140224359

Import ID Number as numbers with leading zeros
ID numbers, account numbers, etc. are sometimes checked for typos using simple math such as Luhn formula. Often these numbers have leading zeros.
In these situations you may want to keep the IDs as numbers with leading zeros. For this purpose I assume all the ID numbers and must be 11 digits. That is, if a number is 10 digits long there will be 1 leading zero. If the number is 9 digits long there will be 2 leading zeros.
Import the CSV file as normal. Highlight the column Phone Number and press Ctrl+1 to get the Format Cells window.

Change the Leading Zeros to 11 as shown above.
Import phone numbers as text
This section is the same as the accepted answer. I put it here to be comprehensive.
When you open the file testcsv.csv in LibreOffice Calc you will get the Text Import window:

Select the Phone Number column by clicking on the word Standard above it. Change Column Type to Text using the drop-down menu. Click OK to import the text file.
Hope this helps.

"That is, if a number is 10 digits there will be 1 leading zero. If the number is 9 digits there will be 2 leading zeros" but in many countries 2 leading zeroes means an international call, and phone umber lengths vary. In the UK most phone numbers will be 10 or 11 digits and start with a 0.  If you prepend another 0 to a 10-digit phone number (which will start 01) and dial it, you'll be trying to call somewhere in North America. Adding a leading zero is as bad as removing one.  Your starting assumption is flawed. -1

...just because a string is all digits, don't treat it as an integer.

You're still making the assumption that you can change the number of leading zeroes, that would conflict with your new statement, except that the Luhn algorithm doesn't care about leading zeroes (and isn't applicable to phone numbers)
